# How to Return two non-consecutive Index Values from an Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
Hope to get help, I must find two data with array. mongodb version 2.6.6
```

test statement:

```
db.test.insert({"student":[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

Know two index 1 and 3, can you use a statement query, find array student[1] and student[3] value.
I only know that query a value, which is the following statement

```
db.test.find({},{'student': {'$slice':[2,2]}})
```

my question was how to find student array two value by a statement query.
I want to output the value 2, 4.

Comment: Array indexes start at `0`. What is the result you want? Match the second position ( index 1 ) only?

Comment: I want find student[1], student[2] by a statement query.

Comment: Sorry but your question is very unclear and you have not made it any clearer in your response. Please show the exact response you want from your query in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, my English is very poor. I have modified the content, I wish I could get your help.

Comment: @FankZhou Would you expect the query output to be `{student: [2,4]}` for your example?

Comment: @JohnnyHK yes, As you said. I want to output the value 2, 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting two indexed positions from an array that are not consecutive in a `$slice` operation is not supported currently and is not really on the immediate books to do as far as I know.

Future releases of MongoDB will have both `$slice` and `$concatArrays` functions that can do exactly what you want though:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "student": { 
            "$concatArrays": [
                { "$slice": [ "$student",1,1 ] },
                { "$slice": [ "$student",3,1 ] }
            ]

        } 
    }}
])
```

Which will output exactly like you want:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56039585091d337d88627dfc"), "student" : [ 2, 4 ] }
```

So that works for me right now running a development release (3.1.7).

For the present you are stuck with two queries, as there is some general "hackery" you can presently do in the aggregation framework for "values" but it is not possible by "index" of the array.

In the shell the basic concept is to run each query and build up a "hash" of the matched document `_id` values and essentially append to each array contained with each indexed position.

Not really a practical example for the shell, but there is something that can be demonstrated with using "parallel" queries and building the "hash" to look like a collection using [`nedb`](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) as an in memory store, and [`node.async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) for the parallel execution as a helper:

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    DataStore = require('nedb'),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient,
    store = new DataStore();

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',function(err,db) {

  var collection = db.collection('test');

  async.parallel(
    [
      function(callback) {
        var stream = collection.find({},{ "student": { "$slice": [1,1] } });

        stream.on("err",callback);

        stream.on("end",callback);

        stream.on("data",function(data) {
          stream.pause();
          data.orig = data._id;
          delete data._id;
          store.update(
            { "orig": data.orig.toString() },
            { "$push": { "student": { "$each": data.student } } },
            { "upsert": true },
            function(err) {
              if (err) callback(err);
              stream.resume()
            }
          );
        });
      },

      function(callback) {
        var stream = collection.find({},{ "student": { "$slice": [3,1] } });

        stream.on("err",callback);

        stream.on("end",callback);

        stream.on("data",function(data) {
          stream.pause();
          data.orig = data._id;
          delete data._id;
          store.update(
            { "orig": data.orig.toString() },
            { "$push": { "student": { "$each": data.student } } },
            { "upsert": true },
            function(err) {
              if (err) callback(err);
              stream.resume()
            }
          );
        });
      }
    ],
    function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      store.find({},function(err,results) {
        console.log(results);
        db.close();
      });
    }
  )

});
```

Which will give you much the same result (sort of):

```js
[ { orig: '56039585091d337d88627dfc',
    student: [ 2, 4 ],
    _id: 'srzH9Z7zIYdET2KJ' } ]
```

Note that while "parallel" is good for performance since both queries are running at the same time, if you need the index order preserved then you would need to run consectively or in "series".

If you need this sort of functionality, you can either use the latter method or wait for the next release of MongoDB. If your app needing this feature is not ready for production yet, then it might be worth your while to start working with a development release in order to be ready for the new features available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.